# reloadRows(at:, with:) causing a crash

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, uitableview, xcode9-beta

I am running Xcode 9 beta 2 and I have a line of code crashing on my device, but not in the simulator.

```
self.tableView.reloadRows(at: [IndexPath(row: count, section: 1)], with: .none)
```

the `count` variable is an `Int()` that the program keeps track of to insert into the correct row. This works fine on the simulator, but on my iPhone 7 Plus running iOS 11 beta 2, it crashes with:

```
Terminating app due to uncaught exception
'NSInternalInconsistencyException', reason: 'UITableView internal
inconsistency: indexPath cannot be nil in
_setupCell:forEditing:atIndexPath:canEdit:editingStyle:shouldIndentWhileEditing:showsReorderControl:accessoryType:animated:updateSeparators:'
```

Is this just a bug or is there something wrong with this line of code?

Comment: What's the complete error message?

Comment: And when working with a `UITableView`, create an `IndexPath` with a row and section. Using an item and section is for `UICollectionView`.

Comment: I added the line of code using a row and section and the error in my question. Changing the line of code still crashes

Comment: When it `crash`, did you check what's the value of `count`. Is the value still in the range of what you expected? <br/> How about try to set a `constant value` instead of `count` and see if it still crash? <br/> When you test on simulator vs the real device, are you using the same type of device?

Comment: Why are you calling `reloadRows` if you are inserting a row?  You should call `insertRows`

Comment: I am actually reloading a row @Paulw11

Comment: I know it's been a while but, are there anyone who found the reason or solution?